# AIR: Adobe Air Debug Launcher stopped working...any logs?

Tags: air, argument-dependent-lookup

I m having trouble with AIR debug launcher(adl) under win 7 64 bits home familial with AIR SDK runtime 2.7. It sometimes crash and i have no posibilities to understand if its because of my software or not.
Does anybody know how I can get some logs to know why it crashed ?
When its crash, the debugger is going away and i dont know where my software bugged if it did...

I have been testing my software under different SDK under win7 and i still had some adl crash. The software is working correctly under winXP. I suppose it has something to do with win7 and AIR but how can I find any informations on what is going on...?

thanks for any tips...

---

i have been able to find windows crash dump files. Then i have download windbg. And started debugging air debugger launcher... but im stuck... not good debugging without symbol files... I guess cant do more then that. The error come from an attempt to convert an integer to a unicode string but i dont know why this function is called, by who and when...

sometimes it doesnt crash also.

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to run/emulate your IDE (flash / Flex) and ADL as a 32bit app. This way you may check if this is really a 64Bit issue.

Comment: I think AIR is 32 bit already so I guess Win7 is doing that by itself, emulating 32 bits for AIR to run. isn't it ?

Comment: Im going to check and try to force that if i can to see any difference.

Comment: no difference. also crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found some windows crash dump log files. Also started to debug with windbg the AIR. :))) lol